# CMake fails in build because cannot find STL libs

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake

I'm trying to use .c and .cpp files in an Android Studio project, i already configure CMakeList with all files that i included.

My CMakeList is like this:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/main/cpp/B/*.cpp")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/A/B/src/a.c
             src/main/cpp/A/B/src/b.c
             src/main/cpp/A/B/src/c.c
             src/main/cpp/A/B/src/d.c
             src/main/cpp/A/a.cpp
             src/main/cpp/A/B/src/e.c
             src/main/cpp/B/a.cpp
             ${SOURCES})
```

Considering that i have directories like this:

```
    +--- /cpp
    |       +--- /A
    |       |    +--- /B      
    |       |    |     +--- /include
    |       |    |     |     +-- *.h
    |       |    |     +--- /src
    |       |    |           +-- *.c
    |       |    |
    |       |    |
    |       +--- /B
    |       |     +--- /include
    |       |     |     +-- *.h
    |       |     +--- /src
    |       |           +-- *.cpp
```

When i run the project i get this

```
../include/a.h:68:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
```

in the **a.h** i have this declaration

```
#include <algorithm>
```

also, in one line that i have: using namespace std, the IDE says that **using** can't resolve type

I think that cmake is kinda of mixing .c and .cpp files in a incorrect way.

Comment: Which file is getting compiled when you get the error message?

Comment: all .c files that includes **a.h** file

Comment: `algorithm` is a **C++** header, it cannot be used from **C** code.

Comment: strangely that i can compile and run successful the same code outside of project, using just a compile.sh file that uses g++. But i will try to change **.c** to **.cpp**

Comment: CMake compiles each source file **separately**; for `.cpp` is uses *g++* compiler, but for `.c` files it uses `gcc`. If your source file requires g++ compiler, then it contains C++ code, and should have corresponded extension.

Answer (score 1):

You are including a C++ header in a C source file (`.c`). You cannot expect `gcc`, the C source compiler invoked by Cmake when it encounters `.c`, to understand C++.

It works in `g++` because that is a C++ compiler. Do note, g++ will treat `.c` files as if they were C++ (The way it does for `.cxx` and `.cpp`). CMake does not do this because [there are many different incompatibilities between C and C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm).